# can flutter display native apps into flutter widget?

Tags: linux, flutter, operating-system, embedded-linux, desktop-application

I have searched this on all websites but, no suitable answer appears, I want the native app to be in the flutter widget like os with app, can flutter do that? especially on linux desktop platforms?

Comment: There is a doable way called as PlatfromView. I have displayed native android and iOS views inside my flutter widget. I am not quite sure of linux, but you can give it a try 

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/platform-views

Answer (score 1):

the answer to your question is yes. you can load other platform native view to flutter the more depth answer is here in flutter **official** **documentation**.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/platform-views

Comment: thanks for answer, but i want to use platform view on linux